# How To Modify LinkedList Property

Tags: c#, linked-list

I want to modify the item's property before I add it to the LinkedList. The item that I'm going to add has two properties:`ProductID` and `ProductValue` like this:

```
public class Product
{

    private byte _productID;
    public byte ProductID
    {
        get { return _productID; }
        set
        {
            _productID = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductID");
        }
    }

    private UInt16 _productValue;
    public UInt16 ProductValue
    {
        get { return _productValue; }
        set
        {
            _productValue = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ProductValue");
        }
    }

}
```

Now I want to modify the item's `ProductValue` according to the previous `ProductID` in LinkedList e.g. If `previous.ProductID = 1`, then `next.ProductValue = previous.ProductValue + 1` But how I supposed to get the property by using `LinkedList<Product> dll = new LinkedList<Product>()`? Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you want to modify this in every item of the linked list? How will you modify it in the first item which has to previous value?

Comment: @MongZhu Except for the first one since it doesn't have the previous node.

Comment: Have you tried using a loop to do that ?

Comment: So what is the method to get the `ProductID` in the LinkedList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So how can I get the ProductID in the LInkedList?

You can get an element in the list using the ElemenAt method to access an element in the `LinkedList`.

Using this method you can iterate with a for-loop through the collection. You can get an element like this:

```
Product previous = dll.ElementAt(i - 1);
```

and access the property like this:

```
if (previous.ProductID == 1)
```

This should make it possible for you to figure out the rest. If you still have difficulties, drop me a comment